# How to find the maximum number in a column for each group of data that are not 0 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, max

I have a large table (17001 x 35), and for one column (the left one in this example), I need to get the largest value in each of the groups. So in this example, the answer would be 56.6, 57.2, and 87.5. The answer would ideally come in a new vector column just listed out. Any help? Seems so simple, but I am a newbie, so alas.

| velocity | marker |
| --- | --- |
| 56.6 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 32.1 | 0 |
| 57.2 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 29.9 | 0 |
| 87.5 | 0 |
| 68.5 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 |

Comment: How are the groups identified? By the `1`s?

Comment: Can values only exist between the corresponding `1` markers when there's a `0`?

Comment: Your title says _for each group of data that are not 0_. However, it seems groups are actually defined by consecutive zeros in the second column. Can you clarify what defines a group? Also, is your data a `table` or a standard numerical array (matrix)?

Comment: So for example does the second group contain two elements (where marker is 0) or three (including the frirst row, for which marker is 1)? If the latter, why does the first group not start with a 1?

Answer (score 0):

If there's a guarantee that no `Velocity` values exits on the indices corresponding to the markers being 1 then we can use the following for-loop approach to accumulate values until we reach a `marker` that is equal to 1. At this point we can dump the `accumulator` and evaluate the corresponding maximum. The `nnz() ~= 0` condition will check to ensure that the whole group stored in the `accumulator` does not contain zeroes.

```
Velocity = [
56.6  0
0     1
0     0
0     0
0     1
32.1  0
57.2  0
0     1
29.9  0
87.5  0
68.5  0
0     1];


Velocity_Values = Velocity(:,1);
Markers = Velocity(:,2);
Accumulator = [];
Maximum_Added = 1;
for Index = 1: length(Velocity_Values)

if Markers(Index) ~= 1
Accumulator = [Accumulator; Velocity_Values(Index)]; 
end

%Dump accumulator%
if Markers(Index) == 1
    if(nnz(Accumulator) ~= 0)
    Maximums(Maximum_Added) = max(Accumulator);
    Maximum_Added = Maximum_Added + 1;
    end
    Accumulator = [];
end
 
end

Maximums = Maximums.';
disp(Maximums);
```

---

### Before the Question Edit:

This approach uses a the `find()` function to figure out where the groups start according to the `1`s in the second column. These indices indicating the start points are then used to index the array and retrieve the chunk of the array corresponding to each group. The maximum of each chunk, `Group` is then taken and stored in an array called `Maximum_Of_Group`. To remove the trivial `0` cases we can conditionally/logically index the array to only take the indices that correspond to a not zero outcome, `~=0`.

```
Array = [
    0       1
    56.66   0
    0       1
    0       0
    0       0
    0       1
    317.18  0
    68.45   0
    107.44  0
    71.39   0
    61.00   0
    85.73   0
    131.90  0
    0       1
    138.28  0
    83.23   0
    0       1
    0       0
    0       0];

Group_Start_Indices = find(Array(:,2) == 1);
Maximum_Of_Group = zeros(length(Group_Start_Indices),1);
for Index = 1: length(Group_Start_Indices)
    
    
    Group_Start = Group_Start_Indices(Index);
    if(Index+1 < length(Group_Start_Indices))
    Group_End = Group_Start_Indices(Index+1)-1;
    else
    Group_End = length(Array);  
    end   
 
    Maximum_Of_Group(Index) = max(Array(Group_Start:Group_End,1));
    
end
    
Maximums = Maximum_Of_Group(Maximum_Of_Group ~= 0);
Maximums
```